# Table data not available in page_source HTML -Python/Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am trying to scrape the odds data contained on https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/chile/primera-division/curico-unido-o-higgins-CtsLggl6/#over-under;2;6.50;0

I am interested in the segment "Over Under" and there the specific over/under odds for two providers, Pinnacle and AsianOdds, which can be found behind the button "compare"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OpwP.png)

When using the developer tools, it can be seen that these are contained in the following HTML:

```html
   <div class=" deactivateOdd" onmouseout="delayHideTip()" onmouseover="page.hist(this,'P-4.50-0-0','4j5hgx1tkucxe2x0',476,event,0,1)">7.54</div>
```

I have already made Selenium to open the page, switch to the Over/Under tab and expand all the "compare" segments.

```html
url='https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/chile/primera-division/curico-unido-o-higgins-CtsLggl6/'
browser.get(url)
browser.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)        


#Open match
match=browser.page_source

# with open("matches.html", "w") as file:
#     file.write(match)

#Click Over/Under Tab
overunder=browser.find_element_by_css_selector("a[title='Over/Under']").click()
#odds_table=browser.find_element_by_class_name("bt-1").click()

#Enter Odds table
odds_table = browser.find_element_by_class_name('bt-1')
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", odds_table)


browser.maximize_window()
odds_rows = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.table-header-light')))

for i in odds_rows:
    count = i.find_element_by_xpath('./span[@class="odds-cnt"]')
    elem = i.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[contains(text(),"Compare")]')
    txt = count.text

    if txt != '' and len(elem):
       elem = elem[0]
       browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elem)
       elem.click()
```

However when running
odds=browser.page_source

with open("odds.html", "w") as file:
file.write(odds)

The resulting page source does not contain the abovementioned HTML that contains the odds..
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You have set the variable match to the page source but haven't used it.

```
match = browser.page_source
if "deactivateOdd" in match:
   #do something
else:
   #do something else
```

I'm pretty sure this is the reason for your elements not showing.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! What I am doing with the page source:
odds=browser.page_source

with open("odds.html", "w") as file:
    file.write(odds)

However the resulting file does not seem to contain the desired HTML..

Comment: Ahh okay I see. Does any code write to the file? And if so, is that code from the desired page you are scraping, or somewhere completely different? Also what are you wanting to be written to the file, the entire page or just the odds bit?

Comment: Yes, there is code written to the file- but it does not include the odds section unfortunately..I would like to pull the entire HTML and then read out the odds section

Comment: Would it not be easier just to print out the odds section into the file? Or is that not what you're looking for? You can use BeautifulSoup to do this and I can tell you how to do it if that's what you're looking for.